# How to create outlet for rootViewController/topViewController with UIViewController Containment

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When creating your own `UIViewController` container, is it possible to have the outlet for your container's rootViewController or topViewController.  With `UINavigationController`, you set the rootViewController in the storyboard.  I was wondering if when creating our own `UIViewController` container, can we do that somehow?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by rootViewController/topViewController -- do you mean the one you add as a child view controller (or if doing it IB, the one that's embedded automatically if you use a container view in the storyboard)? If that's what you mean, there's no way to make an outlet to it in IB, but you can create a property for it in code and set it equal to self.ChildViewControllers[0] (assuming you have only one child).

Comment: ya I was wondering if I could create a container like a uinavigationcontroller where u control click to set its rootViewController. I was hoping we could do the same instead of setting it programitically.

Comment: @Crystal, well it's not exactly like that, but when you use a container view in a storyboard, the controller you automatically get is like a navigation controller's rootViewController -- you just have to refer to it as self.childViewControllers[0] as I said.

Comment: Can you make a reusable container view controller in IB that way?  I downloaded a couple example container view controllers that you can drop in your own view controllers into.  Those were done all in code without storyboards.  THanks.

Comment: @Crystal, yes, in the sense that you can copy and paste view controllers from a storyboard into another storyboard.